# How to find the area of a quadrilateral given only the length of its sides?

Tags: geometry, area, quadrilateral

How do you find the area of a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, given only the length of its sides $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. If the length of a single diagonal is given, I could easily find its area by dividing it into two triangles and applying Heron's formula to each.

I encountered this problem while trying to find the area of a patch of land. Sometimes, the area maybe approximated by a rectangle or a trapezium or some other simple figure, but in general opposite sides are not parallel. All the formulas I have so far seen includes knowing at least one angle or a diagonal.

So is there a formula (even a complicated one maybe) that gives the area of a quadrilateral given only its side lengths?

Comment: FYI : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quadrilaterals are not rigid: you can fix a side and move one of the other vertices freely while respecting all side lengths. The area changes when you move the vertex.

[image]

(image from http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/rigid.html)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/832795/589.

Comment: I see. But if a diagonal is given then it'll be rigid with a unique area right?

Comment: @Nabigh, yes: if a  diagonal is given, then you'll have two triangles, and triangles are rigid.

Comment: Thanks @lhf, that settles the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here you see that the area is not determined. The animation uses parallelograms with side lengths $a=c=3$, $b=d=2$, so the area varies between $0$ and $6$. In general the minimum area may not be exactly zero as here, but the same thing happens always.

[image]